# How can I show errors/warnings above the documentation in the mouse hover popup?

Tags: hover, documentation, visual-studio-code

When I hover my mouse over an error/warning in VSCode, the documentation for that item appears by default. To actually check the error, I need to scroll down. Is there a way to show the error/warning above the documentation by giving it a higher priority?

Example: The documentation for `Response` is shown by default (1st screenshot). But I'm interested in the error, which is visible only after I scroll down (2nd screenshot).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I wish we could configure this, but my workaround is to click on the error and use "Go to Next Problem" which shows just the error for me. (It's bound to command-8 on my computer.)

Comment: Please, upvote this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73120

Answer (score 1):

This was reported as a feature-request issue ticket here: [For long hovers, errors appear all the way at the bottom and require scrolling
#73120](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73120).

A fix has been merged here: [Put marker hovers on top #166560](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/166560):

> This puts marker hovers on top of all other hover kinds, and shifts down all hover kinds that used to be ahead of marker hovers by 1.
>
> An effect of this is that diagnostic messages are now on top when hovering.
>
> - [azdavis](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/166560#issue-1452931129)

It is in [the iteration plan for March 2023](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/176147), and looking at VS Code 1.77 (March 2023 release), it seems that it is part of that version.